# Unable to write a double into a file using BufferedWriter

Tags: java, file, double

Eclipse is prompting me to change the type of the variable to integer but I need it to be a double

w is BufferedWriter, average is a double

`w.write(average);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BufferedWriter` cannot write `double`s, see the [API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write-int-). However, you can convert your `double average` into a `String`, for instance using `Double.toString(average)`  and then write the resulting string with `write(String)`.

Answer (score 2):

A `BufferedWriter` only allows you to write a sequence of characters (the `int` you're seeing is actually a character).

If you want to write anything more complex, such as a `double`, you should use a `PrintWriter` instead.